# Produce historical count of active employees by month

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a SQL novice and have been trying to find a solution to this for some time, but to no avail. My apologies if the solution is nested somewhere in the forums I've missed.

I have this query:

```
Select ID, Start Dt, End Dt
From Employees
```

Which produces the following:

| ID | Start Dt | End Dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2023 | 2/3/2023 |
| 2 | 2/1/2023 | 3/10/2023 |
| 3 | 3/1/2023 | 4/21/2023 |
| 4 | 4/1/2023 | 5/15/2023 |
| 5 | 5/1/2023 | 6/3/2023 |

I would to transform this so that I can produce a count, by month, of employees who were active (active is defined as when month/year is between 'Start Dt' and 'End Dt'). I would like it to look something like this:

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| June 2023 | 1 |
| May 2023 | 2 |
| April 2023 | 3 |
| March 2023 | 2 |
| February 2023 | 2 |
| January 2023 | 1 |

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this? My biggest issue is finding a way to create the date column separate from the data I have, and then connecting that date column to 'Start Dt' and 'End Dt' using the BETWEEN fuction.

I have tried creating a date column and connecting it to employees table like so:

```
Select distinct Dt, count(ID) over (order by Dt)
from Employees
inner join (select trunc (SYSDATE - ROWNUM) Dt
            from dual 
            connect by rownum < 365) dt on dt between Employees.Start_Dt and Employees.End_Dt
```

But I seem to be missing something as there are multiple duplicate rows and the counts aren't adding up. Is my approach incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting the employees each day, not within each month; and you can't just sum those because then you will get duplication of anyone there for more than one day in a month. You're also only looking back 365 days so won't reach the January 2023 data.

If you generate a series of months instead, as the first day of each month for whatever period you want to report on (I've used 18 months back from today; you might want 12 months back from the start of this year, or something else):

```
select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1 - rownum)
from dual 
connect by rownum <= 18
order by 1
```

| ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),1-ROWNUM) |
| --- |
| 01-SEP-22 |
| 01-OCT-22 |
| 01-NOV-22 |
| 01-DEC-22 |
| 01-JAN-23 |
| 01-FEB-23 |
| 01-MAR-23 |
| 01-APR-23 |
| 01-MAY-23 |
| 01-JUN-23 |
| 01-JUL-23 |
| 01-AUG-23 |
| 01-SEP-23 |
| 01-OCT-23 |
| 01-NOV-23 |
| 01-DEC-23 |
| 01-JAN-24 |
| 01-FEB-24 |

then you can join on a range of dates, finding employees who started before the end of that month (or, technically, before the start of the following month), and ended after the start of that month:

```
select to_char(d.dt, 'FMMonth YYYY', 'nls_language=english') as "Month",
  count(e.id) as "Count"
from (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1 - rownum) as dt
  from dual 
  connect by rownum <= 18
) d
join employees e
  on e.start_dt < add_months(d.dt, 1)
  and e.end_dt >= d.dt
group by d.dt
order by d.dt desc
```

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| June 2023 | 1 |
| May 2023 | 2 |
| April 2023 | 2 |
| March 2023 | 2 |
| February 2023 | 2 |
| January 2023 | 1 |

Your expected result had 3 for April, but only two employees were active then, IDs 3 and 4.

If you want to include employees who don't have an end date yet you can add a clause for that - I added an extra open-ended employee starting 2023-12-15:

```
select to_char(d.dt, 'FMMonth YYYY', 'nls_language=english') as "Month",
  count(e.id) as "Count"
from (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1 - rownum) as dt
  from dual 
  connect by rownum <= 24
) d
join employees e
  on e.start_dt < add_months(d.dt, 1)
  and (e.end_dt is null or e.end_dt >= d.dt)
group by d.dt
order by d.dt desc
```

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| February 2024 | 1 |
| January 2024 | 1 |
| December 2023 | 1 |
| June 2023 | 1 |
| May 2023 | 2 |
| April 2023 | 2 |
| March 2023 | 2 |
| February 2023 | 2 |
| January 2023 | 1 |

And if you want to show months with no active employees, which seems unlikely but just in case and to match your limited sample data, you can make it an outer join:

```
select to_char(d.dt, 'FMMonth YYYY', 'nls_language=english') as "Month",
  count(e.id) as "Count"
from (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1 - rownum) as dt
  from dual 
  connect by rownum <= 24
) d
left join employees e
  on e.start_dt < add_months(d.dt, 1)
  and (e.end_dt is null or e.end_dt >= d.dt)
group by d.dt
order by d.dt desc
```

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| February 2024 | 1 |
| January 2024 | 1 |
| December 2023 | 1 |
| November 2023 | 0 |
| October 2023 | 0 |
| September 2023 | 0 |
| August 2023 | 0 |
| July 2023 | 0 |
| June 2023 | 1 |
| May 2023 | 2 |
| April 2023 | 2 |
| March 2023 | 2 |
| February 2023 | 2 |
| January 2023 | 1 |
| December 2022 | 0 |
| November 2022 | 0 |
| October 2022 | 0 |
| September 2022 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2iMag2jq)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and thorough answer. You solved my problem so quick! I have much to learn :). Cheers!